# c# Deserializing an element based on it's parent node's name

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

The XML I'm working with has the following structure:

```
 <fixture_statistics>
  <home_player_1 id="2306143" teamid="2">
   <element_1>Some Data</element_1>
   <element_2>Some Data</element_2>
  </home_player_1>
  <home_player_2 id="2306144" teamid="2">
   <element_1>Some Data</element_1>
   <element_2>Some Data</element_2>
  </home_player_2>
 </fixture_statistics>
```

Now the code to deserialize it would normally look like this:

```
[XmlRootAttribute("fixture_statistics", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class FixtureRoot
    {
        [XmlElement("home_player_1")]
        [XmlElement("home_player_2")]
        public List<FixtureStats> fixtures { get; set; }
    }
    public class FixtureStats
    {
        public string element_1;
        [XMLElement("element_2")]
        public string elementTwo;
    }
```

Here's the question: I'd like the FixtureStats class to have a 'position' property which corrosponds to it's parent's element name (so the FixtureStat object corrosponding to home_player_1 would have position=1).
Can this be done with the built-in serialization atrributes?

If it's not possible, what's the cleanest workaround? Bear in mind that each document will have about 50 player elements, each with about 50 'child' data elements.

Comment: The structure of this Xml document is poorly designed. Are you able to change it so that the suffixes are dropped? If not then there are 3 ways of handling it I can think of: -transform the document before/after serialization by dropping/recreating suffixes (adding additional step), implement IXmlSerializable interface (this is painful), use Linq to Xml to handle serialization (will not be very generic, can get big quickly)

Comment: Agreed. The format of the xml is not under my control, so if it can't be worked with as is, a transformation step would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Would this be useful?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(.....);
var result = 
   xDoc.Descendants("element_1")
   .Select(n => new { Parent = n.Parent.Attribute("id").Value,Value = n.Value, })
   .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var xml = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        int startIndex = 12;
        List<FixtureStats> fixtures =
            (from playerNode in xml.Elements()
             select new FixtureStats
             {
                 position = Int32.Parse(playerNode.Name.LocalName.Substring(startIndex)),
                 element_1 = playerNode.Element("element_1").Value,
                 element_2 = playerNode.Element("element_2").Value
             }).ToList();
```

You have to find the position in the parent element name where the integer part is located. In the case of "home_player_1" it is 12, but you can find with it standard string methods in different cases.